# Prestashop webservice update price of a product

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I use the following code to GET the product form

```
    Dim Req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://mysite.com/api/products/10047")
    Req.Method = "GET"
    Req.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("????????????????????????????????", "")
    Dim Resp As HttpWebResponse = CType(Req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    If Resp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
        Dim dataStream As Stream = Resp.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim R As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        MsgBox(R)
        reader.Close()
        dataStream.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox(Resp.StatusCode & vbCrLf & Resp.StatusDescription)
    End If
    Resp.Close()
```

and I get awnser from the database with all the information of the 10047 product.

how can I update the price of this product?

Comment: Its going to depend entirely on your API.